# How to use multiprocessing pool in a for loop while saving the data?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have some data where I'm trying to apply multiprocessing.pool on it as I have a machine available with 16 processors.
Here do I generate some pseudo data:

```
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(400, high=600, size=1250))
date_today = datetime.now()
x = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(1250), freq='D')
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Price'])
data['Date'] = x
data['Price'] = y
d={name: group for name, group in data.groupby(np.arange(len(data)) // (len(data)))}
```

What I exactly want is that I apply pool in the for loop parameters. So using a processor per constant:

```
parameters = range(300,550,50)
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Parameter','Date','Price','Calculation'])
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    for constante in parameters:
        print('Constante:',constante)
        # HERE I WANT TO USE MP.POOL()
```

In the code I'm using some sort of shifting window to perform calculations on. This is the simplest version of the code. So I want to assign a process per constant in the parameters while writing to a DF. How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `multiprocessing.pool.map` a bit like this, though you'll probably have to adjust for your needs...

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pool_map_fn(value=None, constante=None, i=None):
    s = {'val': value[i:i+constante]}
    window = pd.concat([s['val']['Date'],s['val']['Price']], axis=1)
    window['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(window['Price'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
    calc = window['Price'].mean()                                        
    date_variable = window['Date'].iloc[-1]
    price_var = window['Price'].iloc[-1]
    if price_var < calc:
        print('Parameter',constante,'Lower than average',date_variable,price_var,calc)  
        portfolio = portfolio.append({'Parameter': constante,
                                      'Date': date_variable, 
                                      'Price': price_var,
                                      'Calculation': calc}, ignore_index=True)
    if price_var > calc:
        print('Parameter',constante,'Higher than average',date_variable,price_var,calc)

parameters = range(300,550,50)
portfolio = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Parameter','Date','Price','Calculation'])
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    for constante in parameters:
        with Pool() as pool:
            results = pool.map(partial(pool_map_fn, value=value, constante=constante),
                               range(len(value) - constante + 1))
```

Note: This is untested but should work, if you get errors try to resolve them as the concept should be sound.

Comment: TypeError: pool_map_fn() got multiple values for argument 'value'; struggling with this error

Comment: Try moving the `i` arg to the first arg of that fn, I might have screwed up how the partial receives args, this is mostly off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes that solves it however getting local variable referenced error (portfolio); do you advice using global argument? Just another question as well; is there a variable argument that I can use where I can specify specific number of processors to use?

Comment: Edit: you may have understood the question. Wouldn't the output of the code line '        print('Parameter',constante,'Lower than average',date_variable,price_var,calc)  
' and then the Parameter: constante be different i.e. parallel parameter 300, 350, 400, and 450 if I use let's say 4 processors?

Comment: @JayDough I had this answer as low-quality queue - I flagged your last commet as rude. If the answer has errors : request fixing. If the answer does not suit you, downvote. Dont ask ppl to delete things they invested time in, thats just not done. Nobody forces you to accept this answer.

Comment: @PatrickArtner So if an answer is wrong but they invested time in it; I can't ask to delete it? Brilliant analogy Patrick, well done! Btw; as you can see I've made several attempts asking for revision while I point out arguments so your argument doesn't hold there as well.

Comment: @JayDough thats why I suggested downvoting it. Thats how bad answers are cured in SO - not by asking ppl to delete what they invested time into. I hope that mVChr adresses the problems you pointed out. If not, time will decrease this posts rep. Btw. about 11 months ago I had less rep that you have right now - so please don't throw accusations about "siding" around.